# Efficiently caching data frames in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

The use-case is to self-join a table multiple times.

```
// Hive Table
val network_file = spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM 
test.network_file")

// Cache
network_file.cache()

network_file.createOrReplaceTempView("network_design")
```

Now the following query does self-join multiple times.

```
val res = spark.sqlContext.sql("""select 
          one.sourcehub as source,
          one.mappedhub as first_leg,
          two.mappedhub as second_leg,
          one.destinationhub as dest
          from 
          (select * from network_design) one  JOIN 
          (select * from network_design) two  JOIN 
          (select * from network_design) three  
          ON (two.sourcehub =  one.mappedhub )
          AND (three.sourcehub = two.mappedhub)
          AND (one.destinationhub = two.destinationhub )
          AND (two.destinationhub = three.destinationhub)
          group by source, first_leg, second_leg, dest
          """)
```

Problem is that the Physical Plan of above query suggests on reading the table three times.

```
== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[sourcehub#83, mappedhub#85, mappedhub#109, destinationhub#84], functions=[])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(sourcehub#83, mappedhub#85, mappedhub#109, destinationhub#84, 200)
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[sourcehub#83, mappedhub#85, mappedhub#109, destinationhub#84], functions=[])
      +- *Project [sourcehub#83, destinationhub#84, mappedhub#85, mappedhub#109]
         +- *BroadcastHashJoin [mappedhub#109, destinationhub#108], [sourcehub#110, destinationhub#111], Inner, BuildRight
            :- *Project [sourcehub#83, destinationhub#84, mappedhub#85, destinationhub#108, mappedhub#109]
            :  +- *BroadcastHashJoin [mappedhub#85, destinationhub#84], [sourcehub#107, destinationhub#108], Inner, BuildRight
            :     :- *Filter (isnotnull(destinationhub#84) && isnotnull(mappedhub#85))
            :     :  +- InMemoryTableScan [sourcehub#83, destinationhub#84, mappedhub#85], [isnotnull(destinationhub#84), isnotnull(mappedhub#85)]
            :     :        +- InMemoryRelation [sourcehub#83, destinationhub#84, mappedhub#85], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
            :     :              +- HiveTableScan [sourcehub#0, destinationhub#1, mappedhub#2], HiveTableRelation `test`.`network_file`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [sourcehub#0, destinationhub#1, mappedhub#2]
            :     +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, false], input[1, string, false]))
            :        +- *Filter ((isnotnull(sourcehub#107) && isnotnull(destinationhub#108)) && isnotnull(mappedhub#109))
            :           +- InMemoryTableScan [sourcehub#107, destinationhub#108, mappedhub#109], [isnotnull(sourcehub#107), isnotnull(destinationhub#108), isnotnull(mappedhub#109)]
            :                 +- InMemoryRelation [sourcehub#107, destinationhub#108, mappedhub#109], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
            :                       +- HiveTableScan [sourcehub#0, destinationhub#1, mappedhub#2], HiveTableRelation `test`.`network_file`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [sourcehub#0, destinationhub#1, mappedhub#2]
            +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, false], input[1, string, false]))
               +- *Filter (isnotnull(sourcehub#110) && isnotnull(destinationhub#111))
                  +- InMemoryTableScan [sourcehub#110, destinationhub#111], [isnotnull(sourcehub#110), isnotnull(destinationhub#111)]
                        +- InMemoryRelation [sourcehub#110, destinationhub#111, mappedhub#112], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                              +- HiveTableScan [sourcehub#0, destinationhub#1, mappedhub#2], HiveTableRelation `test`.`network_file`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [sourcehub#0, destinationhub#1, mappedhub#2]
```

Shouldn't the Spark cache the table once and not read it multiple times?
How can we efficiently cache tables in spark for these self-join cases?

Spark Version - 2.2
Hive ORC is the store downstream.

Comment: Why are you doing spark.sqlContext.sql, you can use spark.sql

Comment: I think the physical plan is what is executed at the end. https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-QueryExecution.html

Here is the complete plan. https://pastebin.com/muPamdNA

Comment: Agreed you were correct. pardon me, just checked the spark documentation as well. Let me delete that comment so that people would not be misled.

Answer (score 1):

This sequence of statements ignores the data frame that is to be cached:

```
network_file.cache() #the result of this is not being used at all
network_file.createOrReplaceTempView("network_design") #doesn't have the cached DF in lineage
```

You should either overwrite the variable or register the table on the returned data frame:

```
network_file = network_file.cache()
network_file.createOrReplaceTempView("network_design")
```

Or:

```
network_file.cache().createOrReplaceTempView("network_design")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion and I think the data frame is getting cached now. 

But why is that the Physical Plan has no indication of the table being read from the cached source? 

I couldn't find a difference in the physical plan when we are caching the table.